# How to get microphone input in unreal engine

Tags: unreal-engine4

I want to get the audio input of the microphone in the unreal engine and do some calculations on the samples to draw some cool lines.

I have done that in the unity engine using the unity microphone, but for unreal I don't know how its microphone works, I have searched the unreal documentation and didn't find any useful information. on the unreal engine documentation website, they only show the hierarchy of the microphone class and a little caption for the functions which are not helpful at all for beginners.

I tried `FAudioCapture` but all of its functions kind of empty, and don't do anything. I think it is probably because the microphone must first be initialized or registered somehow and I can't find any information about that.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

i use blueprints from Arthurs Audio BPs at https://github.com/ArthurBarthur/ArthursAudioBPs

Arthur has made many videos, and his BP's are easy to migrate to your own project.